# pyzmq poller for both recv and send messages

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

pyzmq poller does not work if i register it with both POLLIN and POLLOUT.
The if condition could not catch the POLLIN event

### server.py

```
import zmq
import random
import sys
import time

port = "5556"
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
socket.bind("tcp://*:5556")


while True:
    socket.send(b"Server")
```

### client.py

```
import zmq
import random
import sys
import time

port = "5556"
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5556")


poller = zmq.Poller()
poller.register(socket, zmq.POLLIN|zmq.POLLOUT)

while True:
    socks = dict(poller.poll(50))
    if socket in socks and socks[socket] == zmq.POLLIN:
        msg = socket.recv()
        print(msg)
```

Comment: What happens when you do not use the poller and directly call `socket.recv()`?

Answer (score 1):

The integer values for `zmq.POLLIN`, `zmq.POLLOUT` and `zmq.POLLIN | zmq.POLLOUT` are 1, 2 and 3 respectively:

```py
>>> zmq.POLLIN, zmq.POLLOUT, zmq.POLLIN | zmq.POLLOUT
(1, 2, 3)
```

So if in your client side the if statement is expecting receive in the socket it must await for a `zmq.POLLIN` (1) state, but also a `zmq.POLLIN | zmq.POLLOUT` (3) state, since they are exclusive.

Rewriting your if statement:

```py
if socket in socks and socks[socket] in (zmq.POLLIN, zmq.POLLIN | zmq.POLLOUT):
    # your code    
    ...
```

Same way, if you want to send in the socket must await for `zmq.POLLOUT` (2) and `zmq.POLLIN | zmq.POLLOUT` (3) states.